# The easiest way to give true values to a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, logical-operators

I work with a certain data frame and then I ask a logical statement to get TRUE/FALSE data. How can I apply that back to my data frame to get numerical values of those true values alone without the false ones. This is kind of basic, but a lot of sites got me confused, so I relay on you.

An example of what I mean:

```
x<-c(1:6)

y<-x>2
y   
## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

x[y]  
## [1] 3 4 5 6
```

The same concept for a data frame, for instance:

```
    a   b
1   30  932
2   29  711
3   28  475
4   27  338
5   26  586
6   25  463

y<-data_frame_name[ ,2]>500

y
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

How do I apply the same principle without using loops etc. I am sure there is an easy way. In the end I want:

```
    a   b
1   30  932
2   29  711
3   26  586
```

for the example above.

Comment: At the moment this ("numerical values of those true values alone") is rather vague (and probably very basic). Indexing with logical vectors to pick out values is well supported with "[". Build an example with R code and it will be come clear exactly what you do want.

Comment: you're right. I'll put an example

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this sort of subseting by a logical vector is handled with `[`:

```
data_frame_name[y,]
   a   b
1 30 932
2 29 711
5 26 586
```